# Reverse a wipe request for a stolen phone

Tags: remote-wipe

My phone was stolen two days ago and magically found its way back to me today.  I had activated the wipe function for when the phone is turned on.  I'm being told that it hasn't been switched on yet, so I'd like to reverse the request to wipe the phone.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have device management linked with your online account. Check the list of devices, remove the one you set up remote wipe.

Example: I can access mine on https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity after logging in with a Google account from a computer or other phone. Then on https://google.com/android/devicemanager, even if you set up an erase operation, the device should not appear anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to Account, then turn off Find My Device. If it's done with Gmail, then log in with a Google account and turn off the feature. Samsung and iPhone have their own login page to turn off Find My Device.

The best way is to remove the SIM and turn off the internet and all connections. This will stop communication.

Turn on airplane mode on mobile. Then disable ADM under the security tab.

Try to take backup.